# Using Combinatorial proof to conclude $\binom{2n}{n} = 2 \binom{2n-1}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

The question given states: Let x be an element of a set A of size 2n. Among the n-element
subsets of A count those containing x and those omitting x. Conclude that

$\binom{2n}{n} = 2 \binom{2n-1}{n-1}$

So i began like this

So the left hand side has been changed to give the equation
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk^2 = n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}.
$$
replace one factor $\binom nk$ by the equivalent $\binom n{n-k}$, to give as equation to prove
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk\binom n{n-k} = n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}.
$$

Then I was told you are not allowed to solve it Using induction, so now I'm confused on how to go about this question.

Comment: They are asking you to give a *combinatorial proof*, and since they are nice people they have basically written out the whole proof.

Comment: Note that one can give an easy manipulational argument, which is not what is asked for. We have $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$, But $(2n)!=(2n)(2n-1)!$ and $n!=n(n-1)!$.  Cancel an $n$. We get $2\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!n!}$ which is what we want.

Comment: Is there any relation between the part of the question before "So I begun like this" and the part after it? What is the real question?

Answer (score 7):

I have $2n$ different doughnuts, including one made of pure chocolate. I want to choose $n$ doughnuts for a healthy breakfast, saving the rest for lunch. There are $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways to do it. Let us count another way.

(i) For breakfast, I could include the one made of chocolate. Then I would need to choose $n-1$ doughnuts from the remaining $2n-1$. This can be done in $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ ways.

(ii) Or else I could save the pure chocolate doughnut for lunch. Then I would need to choose $n$ from the remaining $2n-1$. This can be done in $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ ways. But this is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

It now follows that $\binom{2n}{n}=2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

**Remark:** One might object that we have used the relation $\binom{2n-1}{n}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ without giving a combinatorial argument.

We could do it like this. The number of ways to choose $n$ doughnuts for breakfast, *not* including the chocolate one, is precisely the number of ways to save $n$ doughnuts for lunch, including the chocolate one. We already saw that this is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

In a grid, the number of ways to go from the origin to the point $(n,k)$ —in the first quadrant—, using only the steps $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n+k}{k},$$ or the same, $\binom{n+k}{n}$. For reference, I recommend *'Principles And Techniques In Combinatorics'* (Chen & Koh).

$\binom{2n}{n}$ counts the number of paths from the origin to $(n,n)$, and the last step of these must come from $(n-1,n)$ or $(n,n-1)$. Then $$\binom{2n}{n}=\binom{n-1+n}{n}+\binom{n+n-1}{n-1}=2\binom{2n-1}{n-1},$$ as desired.