# Combinatorial proof for $ \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{n} = \binom{2n-1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I have to find a combinatorial proof for the following identity:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \binom{2n}{n} = \binom{2n-1}{n}$$

I am really not sure how to formulate the proof because I have a scalar in front of binomial, in this case, a fraction.

Comment: Multiply it to the other side: $\binom{2n}{n} = 2 \binom{2n-1}{n}$. Now you don't have a fraction.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{2n{-}1}{n} = \binom{2n{-}1}{n{-}1} $ since $n + (n{-}1) = 2n{-}1$

Comment: Maybe some combinatorial proof that proves the two identities:

$$\binom{2n}n = \binom{2n-1}{n-1}+\binom{2n-1}n\\
\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \binom{2n-1}n$$

Comment: @peterwhy shouldn´t there be a plus between elements of the right-hand side?

Comment: @peterwhy sorry, have´t seen your correction.

Comment: For $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and for $k \in \{0,1,\cdots, (n-1)\},$ it is routine to algebraically prove that $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}.$  This result dovetails with the previous comments, re $\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \binom{2n-1}{n}.$

Comment: This is my answer from another post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463768/825158

Answer (score 4):

First transform the identity to
$$\binom{2n}{n} = 2 \binom{2n - 1}{n}\ .$$
The left hand side is the number of ways of choosing an $n$ elements subset out of a $2n$ element set $S$. Now specify one element $r\in S$, it can be either included in the chosen subset or not. If it is not included, then we need to choose $n$ elements out of the remaining $2n-1$ elements to form the subset, of which there are $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ ways. If it is included, then we need to choose $n-1$ elements out of $S\setminus \{r\}$, or equivalently, we can choose $n$ elements out of the remaining $2n-1$ elements to exclude, of which there are also $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

Divide a class of $2n$ students into two teams of $n$ members each. The oldest student is present in only one of them. Of all such team formations, $\binom{2n}{n}$ in total, he is present in only half of them and absent in other half.

All possible $n$-strong teams that include the oldest student can also be generated in $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ ways by selecting $n$ of the other $2n{-}1$ students to exclude from joining a team with him.

Comment: This sounds good, but I don't quite understand the second paragraph.

Comment: Reject the oldest only from 2n and now choose n. In its complement, the oldest is present.

Comment: OK I reworded, feel free to change further to your taste. +1

Answer (score 0):

There is a identity which says that $ \binom{n}{k} =  \frac{n}{k} 
 \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ now just compare left and right hand side combinatorial proofs will be like this first we have to choose n persons from 2n persons which is same thing as if one person is fixed then total ways are apparant from here I suppose you can complete

Comment: I assume you're going to edit this quickly to improve equations, but also readability. Sentences would be nice. Don't sacrifice clarity for speed. [MathJax editing guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Sir there is error coming